# Open GL ES 2.0 model view projection matrices multiplication order

Tags: matrix, opengl-es, transformation

I concerned about matrix multiplication order. I've seen multiple examples, some of them multiply like this:
model * view * projection

while others multiply like this:
projection * view * model

I know that the matrix multiplication is not commutative, so which order is the correct one?

Comment: `projection * view * model`

Comment: Ok, I have a code, that contains model * view * projection order, and it works, can you explain why?

Comment: model*view*projection would be correct for row major order matrices, and the other order for Column Major matrices.

Answer (score 2):

You can derive the order by the following logic:

Your object contains vertices, which are vectors. A matrix transformation will be applied to a vector by multiplying it from the left.

What do you want to do in a 3D scene? You want to move your object to the right position (model transformation) then transform it to camera space (view transformation) and finally you want either orthographic, or perspective projection to be applied. In this order you have to apply the matrices to your vertex vector and this leads to the (mathematical correct) order `projection * view * model * vertex`. So you first apply model to your vertex, then view, then projection.

But you can also set brackets to any position in this formula. With the following you can precompute your whole transform matrix with model, view and projection included. Then hand it to your shader and apply this matrix to each vertex as following: `(projection * view * model) * vertex`.

EDIT to your next question: The order in using this in a framework can alter. Because the associativity of `*` in most programming languages is from left to right. And this would be the wrong order in terms of matrix-matrix-multiplication. Remember: Matrix-multiplication goes from right to left! How the calculation in a framework is done depends on its implementation so there is no general rule for it.

Comment: So if the associativity of `*` is left-to-right, then you would write `vertex * model * view * projection`, i.e., `((vertex * model) * view) * projection`?